# import text with emojis in excel

Tags: excel, text, import, utf-8, emoji

I have a lot of txt-files containing text with emojis and other "special" characters (such as é, à, ç...), as well as some Japanese, Hebrew, Cyrillic... in it (encoding is UTF-8). The files always contain multiple texts and metadata about the texts separated by "/". I need to import these files into Excel, have it separated in different rows and columns and then save the document as a CSV-file as well. I have no problem importing and sorting my data in Excel, but the problem is that all of my "special" characters are changed to question marks and I really need them to stay as they are. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you!

edit: my greeting at the beginning keeps disappearing, sorry!

Comment: How do you import your CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the steps:

1. In Excel, click `Data` tab and click `From Text`.
2. Select your file in dialog.
3. In wizard, select your encoding.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I import my data into Excel as a txt-file, then save it as xlsx-file and as a csv-file. You solved the problem I had in the xlsx-file: I am now able to see all of the special characters there. But as soon as I save the xlsx-file as a csv-file, all of the special characters turn into question marks again. Do you know how I can solve this as well?

Comment: @LDG please try: in the save-as dialog set save as type as `Unicode Text(*.txt)`. See [this](https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/excel-csv/excel-save-unicode.png) image.